# Spring Boot Managing Properties File

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to revamp my microservice to maintain a single application yaml rather maintaining multiple profiles. Initially I was maintaining different profiles and the common configurations were repeated across the helm environment specific values yaml. Now the strategy is to move everything to values.yml and maintain environment specific values in config map. The problem I face is my application yml now looks very generic with placeholders and for the same reason the test runs fails as I cannot give a default value for each of the configurations in application.yml. The reason being, For Eg: mongodb cluster endpoint format is different in local to other environment. I managed to place a local specific yaml file under test/resources, but not sure it's the right approach. I need to anyway maintain a local specific yaml under main/resources for running locally. So essentially I am duplicating it under test resources as well. Is there any better way of pointing test to load the application-local.yml under main resources so that I can avoid the duplication or is there any better way of doing this as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.  Working with multiple configs in One File**

You can add all your configurations in one property file as illustrated below

```
spring.application.name: test. ## Used for all profiles
---
spring.config.active.on-profile:dev
spring.database.host: localhost
spring.database.name: testing
---
spring.config.active.on-profile:prod. ##You can use spring.profiles:prod
spring.database.host: localhost
spring.database.name: testing
---
```

`---` marks where yml document splits, while `#---` marks where properties file splits.

Multi-document property files are often used in conjunction with the following activation properties

1. `spring.config.activate.on-profile`
2. `spring.config.activate.on.on-cloud-platform`

All property definitions defined without specifying the profile name are used on all profiles. In the above case `spring.application.name` will be used on all profiles `dev or prod`.

When running the application you can manually specify profile or you can set in within the yml or properties on properties that are used throughout the application.

```
        spring.application.name: test
        spring.profiles.active: prod
```

**2. Testing your application**

when running tests that need to access properties in `yml(property)file` there is

no need to redefine your configurations.Just add `@ActiveProfile("profile-name")`

on your tests.

for example:

```
          @ActiveProfiles("dev")  
          @SpringBootTest(webEnvironmentSpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Comment: Thanks @malvern dongeni. Splitting document with a local profile and setting this as an active profile on base test class solved the issue. However, If I need to run locally, I need to explicitly specify the profile, do you have any suggestion to avoid that as well?

Comment: @vipinev you are welcome you can set that in your IDE.For IntelliJ go to `edit configurations`  then `spring-boot`.under `active profiles` then add your local profile.